# How to programmatically put a custom button in a layout?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm creating a custom settings page where the user can specify which layouts they want a custom button to appear on. I want the user to be able to select Leads, Accounts, Opportunities, and Contacts as possible places for the button.

I can figure out the visualforce part, but how can I make an apex controller that will add a custom button to a layout? That part is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

Page layouts are metadata, stored as xml files, and Salesforce does not offer direct access to the metadata API in Apex.

There is a workaround in [Andrew Fawcett's Apex wrapper for the Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).

[This blog post (also by Andy)](https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/11/22/apex-metadata-api-qa/) looks like it contains some examples that work on Layouts.

[The Layout Metadata API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm) will also be useful to reference if you want to accomplish this. Particularly, that the custom buttons is a collection of strings that reference names of `webLink` objects.

Other things to consider are that you will likely want to allow people to remove your button from their layout(s) via the same custom setting. Also, it'd be a good idea to run a check on your target layout before adding a button to it to make sure that the button doesn't already exist on that layout.